# Error during installing PyOpenCl on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, pyopencl

I follow the installation instructions on http://wiki.tiker.net/PyOpenCL/Installation/Mac . But it falls during

```
make
```

The error message is shown below:

```
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/8f/l7p674mx2j130p08plnd9k1r0000gn/T//ccG1RrCB.out
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What I can do to install PyOpenCL successfully?

Comment: Pyopencl generates unpredictable output on Mac OS. Same code will work perfectly on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [Mako](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Mako/?) before pyopencl?  For some reason that's what works with my macs.

Also, you may not have installed the Xcode Command line tools; try (in the terminal):

```
xcode-select --install
```